# java concurrent Array List access

Tags: java, list, collections, concurrency

I have an object which is a singleton. This object declares:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

The same object also specifies 4 operations on this arrayList:

```
public List<Player> getPlayers() {
return players;
} // the result of this method can be used in another object as an iterator (or maybe by index-access)
```

and

```
public void removePlayer(Player player) {
players.remove(player);
}

public void addPlayer(Player player) {
players.add(player);
}

public boolean isPresent(Player player) {
if (players.constans(player)) {...
}
```

Right now in the constructor I am doing it like that:

```
players = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Player>());
```

But what is the CORRECT way to synchronize these methods. It seems like if I use iterator in another class, it will still through the concurrent modification exception. Does the exception happen if a 2 threads call at the same time the "remove" and "contains" method? There are many threads to access the singleton so I would like to know the method to do this with the minimum hit on performance.

Comment: As explained by tieTYT, every access to the list must be synchronized. This is an utopic goal. So you shouldn't let anyone access the list from outside of your class. Or you should use a concurrent list instead.

Comment: Does the concurrent use of "contains" and "remove" throw an exception?

Comment: If acceptable, you can return copy of list, you can even return unmodifiable copy of list to make sure that any change will fail with exception. For the guys who think that they can add objects without using your API.

Comment: No, because these methods are synchronized. But as soon as you iterate, or do a check-then-act operation such as `if (!list.contains(foo)) list.add(foo)`, you need explicit synchronization. Also beware of hidden iterations such as in `new ArrayList<>(list)`.

Comment: For other options see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207829/best-approach-to-use-in-java-6-for-a-list-being-accessed-concurrently

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The documentation answers your question.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
      ...
  synchronized(list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

As for `contains` and `remove`, you shouldn't have to synchronize manually.  I'm looking at the source code of `Collections` and it looks like it does that for you:

```
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        synchronized (mutex) {return c.contains(o);}
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        synchronized (mutex) {return c.remove(o);}
    }
```

It wouldn't be a synchronized list if you have to do this stuff on your own.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but then what is the value-add of 'Collections.synchronizedList'?  If you synchronize on the original list then doesn't this solve all the problems?

Comment: @TimCooper in the documenation it's stated `Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block`. And yes, my +1 to your question, it sounds logical that `synchronizedList ` is expected to do the job

Answer (score 6):

If you don't plan on updating it often use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) otherwise @tieTYT's suggestion works.

You can also manage this yourself by returning a copy of the list instead of the actual list within the `getPlayers`. (If you are using `Collections.synchronizedList`)

```
public List<Player> getPlayers(){
    synchronized(list){
       Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Player>(list));
    }
}
```

This has the side effect of a list being out of date after an add/remove is done

**Edit:** *Stealing Grzegorz suggestion for `unmodifiableList`*

Comment: wouldn't it be out of date after u synchronized it anyway?