# Write an ArrayList with integers which will be accessed concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, atomic

The requirement is that, I need to write an ArrayList of integers. I need thread-safe access of the different integers (write, read, increase, decrease), and also need to allow maximum concurrency.

The operation with each integer is also special, like this:

1. Mostly frequent operation is to read
2. Secondly frequent operation is to decrease by one only if the value is greater than zero. Or, to increase by one (unconditionally)
3. Adding/removing elements is rare, but still needed.

I thought about AtomicInteger. However this becomes unavailable, because the atomic operation I want is to compare if not zero, then decrease. However the atomic operation provided by AtomicInteger, is compare if equal, and set. If you know how to apply AtomicInteger in this case, please raise it here.

What I am thinking is to synchronized the access to each integer like this:

```
ArrayList <Integer> list;
 ... ...
// Compare if greater than zero, and decrease
MutableInt n = list.get(index);
boolean success = false;
synchronized (n) {
    if (n.intValue()>0) { n.decrement(); success=true; }
}

// To add one
MutableInt n = list.get(index);
synchronized (n) {
    n.increment();
}

// To just read, I am thinking no need synchronization at all.
int n = list.get(index).intValue();
```

With my solution, is there any side-effect? Is it efficient to maintain hundreds or even thousands of synchronized integers?

Update: I am also thinking that allowing concurrent access to every element is not practical and not beneficial, as the actual concurrent access is limited by the number of processors. Maybe I just use several synchronization objects to guard different portions of the List, then it is enough?

Then another thing is to implement the operation of add/delete, that it is thread-safe, but do not impact much of the concurrency of the other operations. I am thinking ReadWriteLock, for add/delete, need to acquire the write lock, for other operations (change the value of one integer), acquire the read lock.  Is this a right approach?

Comment: `n++` and `n--` won't actually change the value in the `List`. It makes more sense to use the list as the lock, not the list's elements.

Comment: Does it have to be an `ArrayList` or is any list ok?

Comment: If you allow concurrent add/remove of elements, how will you know which element to update? Index won't work, because a remove might shift the index between caller supplied the index and method accesses the element.

Comment: I think you have answer in this thread : 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578299/java-concurrent-array-list-access

Comment: @Paul Use the list as the lock definitely works. But as I said I need concurrent operation towards the different values of the integers. It is not necessary to lock the whole list if changing a specific value of the element.

Comment: @Andreas  Need to be ArrayList like, as a ramdom access is frequent. Because as you said, removing will shift the index, so I am thinking to use ReadWriteLock to protect this, the operation of getting an integer and change it, is regarded as a Read to the List, while add/remove elements are regarded as Writes to the List.

Comment: @parmeshwor11 I read through that question, and looks like the suggestion is still synchronization on the whole list, which as I said, unnecessary for me.

Comment: Yeah, but remember that the read lock has to surround the code that determines the index to update, whatever weird logic that is. I mean, if list has thousands of integers, how does the code know that e.g. the integer at index 847 is the one to update? The read lock has to be established *before* the code begins to figure out what index to update, and keep the read lock until after the update has completed.

Comment: @Andreas,  yeah you have a good point for surround the code of determining the index. I agree with it. : )

Comment: @GordonLiang Can you clarify what the operations are? For example, is the `increase` operation to find the element at a specific index and increase it, or look for a particular number (e.g. `5`), and if it exists in the list, make it `6`?

Comment: @Paul increase means increase the value at a specific index, no looking here.

Comment: I just realized Integer is not mutable, and n++, n-- results in a new object. I think this breaks the curent logic, so I need to use wrapper, or MutableInt.
I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right to use read lock for accessing the list and write lock for add/remove on the list.

You can still use `AtomicInteger` for the values:

```
// Increase value
value.incrementAndGet()

// Decrease value, lower bound is 0
do {
    int num = value.get();
    if (num == 0)
        break;
} while (! value.compareAndSet(num, num - 1)); // try again if concurrently updated
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks a little wired to me at the beginning, however I think it works. Actually this is written in a similar way that the other operation of AtomicInteger is written...  looks like compareAndSet is a magic atomic operation.

Comment: Comparing the option of synchronizing the object, and the one with AtomicInteger and retry mechanism as you wrote,  how do we compare the performance?

Comment: You mean performance in worst-case scenarios or normal use scenarios? In a normal use scenario I'd expect this to be better, because it's not wasting time establishing a synchronize lock. In a worst case scenario with extremely high contention on a *single* integer (very unlikely if you have thousands of integers), this code will use a bit more CPU in the retry loop, but whether that's worse than the synchronize waits is unknown. To compare performance, you'd just put it under heavy "normal" load.

Comment: Keep in mind that if `compareAndSet` fails, it implies that another thread *has* made progress. As long as the loop’s body is a cheap operation (as decrementing an `int` is), this is at least on par with a `synchronized` operation. It may happen that a particular thread never makes progress while other threads outpace it, but `synchronized` also makes no fairness guaranty…

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you can live with a fixed size list, using a single `AtomicIntegerArray` is a better choice than using multiple `AtomicInteger`s:

```
public class AtomicIntList extends AbstractList<Integer> {

  private final AtomicIntegerArray array;

  public AtomicIntList(int size) {
    array=new AtomicIntegerArray(size);
  }
  public int size() {
    return array.length();
  }
  public Integer get(int index) {
    return array.get(index);
  }
  // for code accessing this class directly rather than using the List interface
  public int getAsInt(int index) {
    return array.get(index);
  }
  public Integer set(int index, Integer element) {
    return array.getAndSet(index, element);
  }
  // for code accessing this class directly rather than using the List interface
  public int setAsInt(int index, int element) {
    return array.getAndSet(index, element);
  }
  public boolean decrementIfPositive(int index) {
    for(;;) {
      int old=array.get(index);
      if(old<=0) return false;
      if(array.compareAndSet(index, old, old-1)) return true;
    }
  }
  public int incrementAndGet(int index) {
    return array.incrementAndGet(index);
  }
}
```

Code accessing this class directly rather than via the `List<Integer>` interface may use the methods `getAsInt` and `setAsInt` to avoid boxing conversions. This is a common pattern. Since the methods `decrementIfPositive` and `incrementAndGet` are not part of the `List` interface anyway, they always use `int` values.

Comment: This is an interesting solution and I like the idea of avoiding boxing. What is the pattern called? 
How about I really need to expand the array occasionally, can I still use this solution? My idea is that, when an expansion needed, I may create another AtomicIntegerArray with new size, and copy the old values. I think I can still use the read/write lock in this case: apply the write lock when I want to expand the list, which blocks all read access before the restructure completes.

Answer (score 0):

As an update of this question... I found out that the simplest solution, just synchronizing the entire code-block for all possible conflict methods, turns out to be the best, even from performance's point of view. Synchronizing the code block solves both issues - accessing each counters, and also add/delete elements to the counter list.

This is because ReentrantReadWriteLock has a really high overhead, even when only the read lock is applied. Comparing to the overhead of read/write lock, the cost of the operation itself is so tiny, that any additional locking is not worthy doing that.

The statement in the API doc of ReentrantReadWriteLock shall be highly put attention to: "ReentrantReadWriteLocks... is typically worthwhile only when ... and entail operations with overhead that outweighs synchronization overhead".