# Is there a Kotlin equivalent of Java's Collections.synchronizedList ? Or is this not needed in Kotlin

Tags: java, list, concurrency, kotlin, thread-safety

Coding in Kotlin, want a thread-safe List as described here: [java concurrent Array List access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578299/java-concurrent-array-list-access)

It seems Collections.kt does not have this function. Are Kotlin's mutable lists already threadsafe ? If not, how do I accomplish this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the Java one? It will work fine since Kotlin is completely interoperable with Java. Kotlin's mutable lists are not thread-safe.

Comment: @Shadov I don't think Kotlin's collection library is interoperable with the JDK's.

Comment: If I try to use the Java List a warning message comes up "This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin..."  Not sure if that is merely a suggestion or serious direction due to some issue...

Comment: @shmosel Yes, it is: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Interesting. So does that mean you can actually use the `Collections` wrappers?

Comment: @shmosel Yes (in a JVM-only project, of course).

Comment: A thread-safe ArrayList [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> If I try to use the Java List a warning message comes up "This class shouldn't be used in Kotlin..."

Java lists (and other collections) are [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) in Kotlin. So you *can* use `Collections.synchronizedList`, and it takes and returns a Kotlin `List` or `MutableList`.

OTOH, `synchronizedList` is rarely what you actually want: it works for single method calls, but anything else must be synchronized manually.

Comment: Right, it doesn't really prevent `ConcurrentModificationException`, for example. You can still get it while accessing the list from two different threads using two methods/functions at the same time.

Comment: So there is no completely synchronized collection in Kotlin right now?

Comment: As far as I know it's impossible to create one, in Kotlin or in Java. It _has_ to be specific to your project because different projects need different operations to be atomic.

Comment: @milosmns because you didn't read description of this method `It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it`. So `Collections.synchronizedList` should work fine https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-

Comment: @user924 Nah, I waited 3 years for you to read it for me and point out that I didn't do it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CopyOnWriteArrayList is a thread-safe variant of Arraylist